# How do I use the Shop Mart shopping cart?

Tags: neo-scavenger

On a couple of my attempts to survive, I've run across the Shop Mart shopping cart, and I just cant figure out how to use it. The [Wikia entry](http://neoscavenger.wikia.com/wiki/Shop_Mart_shopping_cart) for this item claims it is a vehicle that provides a 16x16 storage area "when used" from the vehicle screen. Although I am most likely missing something quite obvious, I cannot find any way to actually do this.

Dragging it onto various locations on the paper-doll yield no results, and various amounts of clicking and/or dragging on any other screen (vehicle or otherwise) have resulted in a similar amount of nothing. I'm hesitant to try placing any of my items into the cart, as [*this question*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89244/is-there-any-way-to-access-the-contents-of-an-item-without-equipping-it) demonstrates that that items can only be retrieved from containers by equipping them - which is something you cannot do with the cart.

So, any tips on how to turn this item into a working vehicle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory, the cart should be equippable like clothes, backpacks, etc. It would install in the vehicle slot on the "Vehicle" screen (button that looks like a truck, or hotkey V).

The easiest method would be to put the shopping cart on the "Ground" (if not there already), switch to "Click to take/drop" (hotkey 1), then click on the cart. It should automatically fly to the vehicle slot (the slot looks like a truck).

You can also use "Click to move" to pick up and drop the cart into the vehicle slot, but you'd have to be on the vehicle screen for that.

I say "in theory" because there's always the chance I broke something. It's working on my current test build, but let me know if it isn't for you!

Comment: As I said, I'm probably missing something quite obvious - I'll give it a shot next time I find one.